# Uninstalling the module from drupal-7

Tags: 7, commerce

I had installed module **Commerce** and it was giving me error whenever I try to display product.Then I went through forums to find out solution. And reason mentioned in forum was `commerce` module might not installed properly due to maximum execution time.So I decide to uninstall **commerce** module and  I have done. Also removed it from the `sites\all\modules`. I have cleared all the caches.

But question is that after removing the module, `product`(which is part of the commerce module) is still showing up in admin navigation bar at top.

I know it is not coding related question but still any help would be appreciated.

[image: Uninstalling module]

Comment: clear the browser caching...

Comment: I have done that.But still same result.**Product** is not working but still is shows up in the admin menu.When I click on that it fires this error : `Notice: Undefined index: sku in views_handler_filter->accept_exposed_input() (line 1273 of C:\wamp\www\drupal-7.31\sites\all\modules\views\handlers\views_handler_filter.inc).`
What might be the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps. From these steps I think your query may solved.

1. Clear caching from the drupal.
2. Clear caching from the database.
3. Clear browser caching.

& check. If the menu again shows then
**Goto**

```
Admin -> Structure -> Menu -> Management -> list links
```

& check

**Clear Caching from the database (local server)**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE cache; 
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_advagg_aggregates;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_advagg_info;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_block; 
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_bootstrap; 
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_field; 
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_filter; 
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_form; 
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_image; 
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_menu; 
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_page; 
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_path; 
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_update; 
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_views; 
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_views_data;
```

Comment: How to clear cache from the database ?

Comment: In your db there are lots of cache table. You can delete the caching data from those tables. Do you know how to delete ? I think you are using local server am I right ?

Comment: Yes there are lots of cache table.So I need to empty all those table ? Or Do I need to do in different way ?

Comment: Check updated answer. Add more truncate query if more tables are there except those in your database.

Comment: Working .. I am little bit slow ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17885/discussion-between-samzha-and-twix).

Comment: Ok .. Truncated all the tables.Do I need to clear my browser cache again ?

Comment: you may try once.

Comment: Ok .Doing..Why am I not able to reply from chat room ?

Comment: got any result ?

Comment: Tried all the things but still no result.With your suggestion I am able to hide but not able to delete it.

Comment: did you check "Admin -> Structure -> Menu -> Management -> list links"

Comment: Yah ..Through that I have hide that. But I want to delete it permanently.

Comment: It is not completely solved.So if no one able to solve than I'll accept it so that other can resolve from this question.Can you tell me how to delete my drupal site completely from the localhost ?

Answer (score 0):

Visit admin/modules/uninstall, check if its uninstalled.

Check once again DRUPAL_ROOT/sites/all/modules for commerce module, if exist delete the folder.
and still not solved

Clear the cache twice thrice
still not solved

If you have ssh access to your project clear cache via drush
still not solved

Restart mysql and apache2
still not solved

put site in maintenance mode and reboot the live server.

For further help visit [How to fix error found in Drupal Commerce after installation](https://drupalcommerce.org/discussions/6683/how_fix_error_found_drupal_commerce_after_installation)

Comment: I am using `local host`. Done all your steps except drush and maintenance mode.But still it is showing :(